# Add export customize by default

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

How can I add export button and its customize function by default like this

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
language: {
"loadingRecords": "Loading. Please wait...",
"info": "Showing <span class='startPage'>START</span> to <span class='endPage'>END</span> of <span class='totalPage'>TOTAL</span> entries",
"lengthMenu": "Showing MENU entries"
},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend with a `buttons` literal :

```js
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  buttons: [{ 
     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
     customize: function(doc) {
        doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 40; 
     }   
   }]  
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/t438mzLk/**

Comment: $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'abcd',
    customize: function (xlsx) {
      var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
      $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '42');
    }
  }]
});

Comment: @GeethuNimesh Your code seem to work here -> **https://jsfiddle.net/t438mzLk/1/** i.e also calling the `customize` callback. I have absolutely no experience with manipulating Excel sheets (if that is the problem), does not even have excel on the computer I am sitting at right now :) If the buttons not is shown at all, or the `customize` callback not is executed, then you should upgrade buttons.dataTables.js, buttons.html5.js and so on.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to define some default customization globally and I need to add specific customization on different pages, which should override the globals. https://jsfiddle.net/t438mzLk/5/